# Using terraform to update existing Azure APIM

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-api-management

I have a no. of API management services setup on Azure already but they are not provisioned using Terraform. Now I want to using terraform to update the backend HTTP endpoint and policies. Is it possible to do so? Is there any data sources for apim I can use? Any example I can refer to?

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

Initially, I created **`Azure APIM management service`** using below terraform code.

**`main.tf`**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
   }                           
  

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "rg3"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_api_management" "example" {
  name                = "venkat-demo"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  publisher_name      = "My Company"
  publisher_email     = "company@terraform.io"

  sku_name = "Developer_1"
}

resource "azurerm_api_management_api" "example" {
  name                = "venkatdemo326"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  api_management_name = azurerm_api_management.example.name
  revision            = "1"
  display_name        = "vjtestAPI"
  path                = "example"
  protocols           = ["https"]

  

  import {
    content_format = "swagger-link-json"
    content_value  = "http://conferenceapi.azurewebsites.net/?format=json"
  }
}
```

**Portal:**

[image]

> Now I want to using terraform to update the backend HTTP endpoint and policies

You can use the below terraform code to create resources that manage the backend HTTP endpoint and policies of that service.

**`main.tf`**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
   }   
   
data "azurerm_api_management" "example" {
  name                = "venkat-demo"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_api_management_backend" "example" {
  name                = "backend1"
  api_management_name = data.azurerm_api_management.example.name
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_api_management.example.resource_group_name
  protocol            = "http"
  url                 = "https://example.com/api"
}

resource "azurerm_api_management_policy" "example" {
    api_management_id = data.azurerm_api_management.example.id
    xml_content = <<XML
<policies>
  <inbound>
    <find-and-replace from="xyz" to="abc" />
  </inbound>
</policies>
XML
}
```

**Console:**

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

**Reference:**

- [azurerm_api_management_backend | Resources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform Registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/api_management_backend)
- [azurerm_api_management_policy | Resources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform Registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/api_management_policy)

Comment: Thanks! But it looks like you are using Terraform to create the APIM and then update it. But for my case the apim is not created by Terraform. So do I need to import those APIM first before I can update the backend and policies of them?

Comment: Yes, you can import those Apim https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/api_management_backend#import

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change an Azure resource (in this case Azure APIM), you'll have to first declare the resource with the corresponding resource type (in this case [azurerm_api_management](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/api_management)) and then to [import](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/api_management_backend#import) your existing resource into your [Terraform's state](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/state).

After importing, on the subsequent execution of `terraform plan`, you'll see the changes terraform would like to execute based on the difference between your declaration and the current state of your APIM instance.

You cannot use a terraform data source (like [this](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/api_management)) if you want to change (=manage) the resource. Data sources can only be used to read attributes from resources.